# Vaciar BD sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Saludos quisiera vaciar toda mi base de datos sin tener que hacerlo tabla por tabla con la opcion TRUNCATE, digase que quiero vaciar las tablas no borrararlas que es lo que haria un DROP sino solo el contenido. Se pueden vaciar todas(8 tablas) en una sola sentencia junta.

Comment: Lo que buscas no es ni mas ni menos que un `truncate` ordenado de tus 8 tablas, no hay otra funcionalidad. Eventualmente una vez que tengas tu base "en blanco", puedes guardarla mediante un `backup` para luego restaurarla mediante un `restore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que tienes 2 opciones:

1. **procesos o funciones en SQLserver:** crear una funcion que recorra todas las tablas que tengas y al ejecutarce las deje limpias .
2. **Usar un lenguaje externo:** Crear una estructura en algun otro lenguaje que se conecte con SQLerver **(c#,java,etc),** y ahi hacer una logica que limpie toda la BD.

Yo hice algo como esto para el proposito que pides:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE
(
    texto Varchar(50)
)
insert into #TEMPTABLE
SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE '+SYSOBJECTS.NAME FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE SYSOBJECTS.XTYPE = 'U'


declare @count int = 0,
  @countb int = 1;
set @count = (select COUNT(*) from #TEMPTABLE)
while @count < @countb
begin
    execute sp_executesql select TOP(@countb)texto from #TEMPTABLE
    set @countb = @countb+1;
end
DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLE
```

Lo que hace basicamente es crear una tabla con un varchar y se le inserta la siguiente

```
(SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE '+SYSOBJECTS.NAME FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE SYSOBJECTS.XTYPE = 'U')
```

que lo que hace basicamente es que te añade 'TRUNCATE TABLE'+ nombre de la tabla, esto lo hace con todas las tablas de la base de datos.

quedaria algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y despues recorre esta tabla ejecutando **TRUNCATE TABLE #** columna por columna cada tabla, y al final elimina la tabla provicional que cree **#TEMPTABLE**.

**NOTA:** Claro, tienes que tener una logica dependiendo de la estructura de tu base de datos para que no ocurran problamas con **pk's o fk's**, en este caso no tengo en cuenta las relaciones debes de ordenar los registros de **#TEMPTABLE** para no tener problemas.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes crearte un script de la Base de datos donde puedes seleccionar las tablas que desees y en el script solo se va a guardar la estructura de la Base de datos (tablas, llaves), una vez tengas el script realizas el drop database y después cargas el script. Esto puede servirte si tienes muchas tablas.